# AOP not working form Multiple project Spring java framework

Tags: aop, spring-aop, sap-commerce-cloud

I have done all implementation suggestion.
Basically I have four differnt module (core, service layer, rest webservices, Web base project)
I have created my AOP file (*aop.xml*) is create in my web base project */web/resources/META-INF*.
And my web base project internally depends on service layer project.

So I want to apply my logger on both project, But it's working only for web base project not form service layer project.

Please look my code If I have miss out some thing.

My *aop.xml* // Location of aop is web application extension : *resources/META-INF*

```xml
<weaver options="-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true">
    <include within="com.xyz.storefront..*" />
    <include within="com.xyz.facades..*" />
</weaver>
<aspects>
    <aspect class="com.xyz.storefront.aop.CustomLogger" />
</aspects>
```

My Aspect Code

```java
@Aspect
 public class CustomLogger {
     private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

     @After("execution(* com.xyz.storefront.controllers.pages.AjaxRequestController.addProductToCart(..))")
     public void addProductToCartAfterBefore(final JoinPoint point) {
         log.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " Before..." + new Date());
     }

     @Before("execution(* com.xyz.storefront.controllers.pages.AjaxRequestController.addProductToCart(..))")
     public void addProductToCartAfter(final JoinPoint point) {
         log.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " After..." + new Date());
     }

     @Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.facades.order.impl.DefaultMswCartFacade.addToCartNew(..))")
     public void DefaultMswCartFacade(final JoinPoint point) {
         log.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " After..." + new Date());
     }
 }
```

Thanks, Vishal Patil

Comment: show us your spring config files (*xml or java as applicable*)

Comment: The third advice has a syntax problem: Either you define a stand-alone `@Pointcut` with an empty code block and apply it later in an advice or you define an anonymous pointcut directly withing an advice like `@Before` or `@After` just in your first two advices.

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond  thanks for your answer I solved my problem.